# What's the usage of double colon in sql using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I saw this in a node.js project.

sequelize.query("select * from user where user.age=::age", 
{replacements:{age:20}});

Why does he use double colon rather than single colon?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#querysql-options-promise) it seems you need a single colon. Replacements can be named using a colon or anonymous using a question mark. e.g.

```
sequelize.query("select * from user where user.age=:age", {replacements:{age:20}});
```

or

```
sequelize.query("select * from user where user.age=?", {replacements:[20]});
```

Comment: Yes,I do think so. Strangely double colon also works. I found this in the docs,I don't understand $1::varchare here.              "The database may add further restrictions to this. Bind parameters cannot be SQL keywords, nor table or column names. They are also ignored in quoted text/data. In PostgreSQL it may also be needed to typecast them, if the type cannot be inferred from the context $1::varchar."      http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/

Comment: I saw that too. Double colons are used in some databases (esp. PostgreSQL). However, given the context of your question though I figured it must be a typo. Confusing behaviour if it works anyway - I would prefer an error!

Answer (score 0):

Oh,I guess I got it. @chriskelly you're right. one more colon will also match the RegEx,and two more colon will also work. i.e. ::::age is accepted, too.

```
SqlString.formatNamedParameters = function(sql, values, timeZone, dialect) {
return sql.replace(/\:+(?!\d)(\w+)/g, function(value, key) {
if ('postgres' === dialect && '::' === value.slice(0, 2)) {
  return value;
}

if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  return SqlString.escape(values[key], false, timeZone, dialect);
} else {
  throw new Error('Named parameter "' + value + '" has no value in the given object.');
}
});
};
```